# React State remains immutable when i try to show component onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have button with onClick function like this :

```
<button className="btn" onClick={(e) => handleClick(user._id, e)} >Edit</button>
```

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)


const handleClick = (id, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setShow(!show)
    dispatch(getUser(id))}

/* And here rendering based on State */
{
  show ? renderUserData() : null
}
```

So, problem is that setShow(!show) inside the handleClick function does not work and state of show remains false, immutable. if handleClick function contains only setShow(!show) then this function working and toggling renderUserData(), but when it contains both dispatch(getUser(id)) and setShow(!show), state of show remains false all time,please help

Comment: If you add `console.log("mounting")` right below `const [show, setShow] = useState(false)` will it print again after you clicked the button?

Comment: yes, it is printing @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: Which means your `dispatch` somehow triggers a process that dismounts the components and mounts a brand new one. It is not that state is immutable, it's just completely different state of a different component. You need to look at your component's parent to figure out why it's doing this. (Also `preventDefault` indeed can be remove but doesn't make any difference to your issue)

Comment: Object { type: "GET_USER_REQUEST" }
mounting ,
Object { type: "GET_USER_SUCCESS", payload: {…} }
mounting.

console shows mounting 2 times, I agree with you that dispatch somehow triggers a process that dismounts the component. i am very grateful for your help need to solve it asap. @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: Oh, actually the log has to be inside `useEffect` (sorry about that). If you add `useEffect` like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/931wtLm0/ and your component is indeed dismounted you can add a breakpoint there and hopefully see what triggers it

Answer (score 2):

try to remove the `e.preventDefault()` you can play around with your own data but the `e.preventDefault()` is not useful in buttons (if you have a form try to put it in the `onSubmit` of the form) but the final solution must look something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (id, e) => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {show ? <h1>Data showed</h1> : null}
      <button className="btn" onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: removing e.preventDefault() doesn't solve the issue, problem is that inside the handleClick function setShow and useDispatch does not work together, if I comment dispatch action then setShow works, but not together.

Comment: @GIorgi then try to put them inside anonymous functions and call them right away: ```;(function () {setShow(!show)})() 
;(function () {dispatch(getUser(id))})() 
``` try to copy and paste this code and replace the ```dispatch``` and ```setShow``` with it

Comment: I tried to setTimeout on dispatch and saw that, setShow(!show) works until dispatch(getUser(id)) action call is made, dispatch makes setShow always to false. please help me I am stuck on it second day.

Comment: can you provide some more information or send a link to your repository? because it seems like to me the code has no bugs in it and it should work perfectly. if there's a repository link you can send it would be much easier for me to debug the code

Comment: https://github.com/Giorgi-Kirvalidze/mern-admin

this is a repository, so keep in mind my problem is in src/containers/Users/index.js, especially handleClick function on pressing the "edit" button handleClick function is invoked, my aim is that I want to toggle rendering component and make dispatch action at the same time. if you comment out dispatch, then setShow(!show) is working,  but when action is dispatched it sets state of show default value to false.

Comment: how can I trigger the button? where is it?

Comment: you need admin privileges I have,mern-server repository there, it is pretty hard, thxs for you trying , forget it ,I will find workaround.